# Create custom taxonomy and Display in metabox dropdown

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox, taxonomy, tags, dropdown

I'm looking to create a dropdown in the post edit screen which contains 3 already existing tags. What's the easiest way of doing this?

Basically all I'm looking for is a simple drop down which adds one of the following tags to the post itself; 'beef-stew', 'pea-soup' & 'chili'. I'd also like 'beef-stew' to be the default.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: As I don't want the user to be able to display more than 1 of these 3 categories at any time, and have to option to easily change which one as they please, tags might not be the best solution? Would I be better off creating a custom taxonomy ('food')? They will basically be used to change the way a post is displayed on the front page of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this handy guide and it worked a treat:

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-input-panels

Answer (score -1):

> Create Custom Post Type

```
function create_product()
{
   $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Product', 'post type general name', 'stacy' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'product', 'post type singular name', 'stacy' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Products', 'admin menu', 'stacy' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Product', 'add new on admin bar', 'stacy' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'product', 'stacy' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Product', 'stacy' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Product', 'stacy' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product', 'stacy' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Product', 'stacy' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Product', 'stacy' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Product', 'stacy' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Product found.', 'stacy' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Product found in Trash.', 'stacy' )
);
   $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'Add New Product on stacy' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'product' ),
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => 100,
            'menu_icon'          =>'dashicons-cart',
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail','comments','capabilities' ),
            'taxonomies'         => array('product_category','product_tag')
);
    register_post_type( 'product', $args );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'create_product' );
```

> Create Custom Metabox and Display meta value on edit post

```
  function add_product_details_meta_box()
  {
   global $wpdb;
   global $post;
   $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
   <p>
    <label>Short Description:</label><br />
    <textarea rows="5" name="short_description" class="width99"><?= @$custom["short_description"][0] ?></textarea>
   </p> 
   <p>
    <label>Price:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="price" value="<?= @$custom["price"][0] ?>" class="width99" />
   </p>

    <p>
    <label>Dimensions (in):</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="length" value="<?= @$custom["length"][0] ?>" class="s" placeholder="Length"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>Shipping Lead Days:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="ship_lead_days" value="<?= @$custom["product_ship_lead_days"][0] ?>" class="s" placeholder="Shipping Lead Days"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>Commision:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="commision_broker" value="<?= @$custom["commision_broker"][0] ?>" class="s" placeholder="Enter Your Commision Here"/>
    </p>
   }
  add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_product_meta_boxes' );
```

> Update Post Meta

```
function save_product_custom_fields(){
 global $post;

 if ( $post )
 {
   update_post_meta($post->ID, "short_description", @$_POST["short_description"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "price", @$_POST["price"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "length", @$_POST["length"]);
       update_post_meta($post->ID,'product_ship_lead_days',@$_POST['ship_lead_days']);
 update_post_meta($post->ID,'commision_broker',@$_POST['commision_broker']);
  }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_product_custom_fields' );
```

Comment: Can you just explain a little bit in addition to code

Comment: first code for create a custom post type 
second code for meta box that you want to some custom fields on your post type.

Comment: last code for update meta box value on post meta